# How to get URL of images in Forum Posts?

Tags: moodle

I am making my own variation of the Latest Announcement block for the dashboard. I want to make the forum posts visible in this block as cards with the attached images.

I found that I need to add HTML in blocks/news_items/blocks_news_items.php file's $text variable.

And I found that the URL of the forum post is passed as rendering context to the mustache file in mod/forum/templates/forum_discussion_post.mustache:

```
{{#urls.image}}
<a href="{{urls.group}}" role="button" aria-label='{{#str}} memberofgroup, group, {{name}}{{/str}}'>
<img
class="rounded-circle w-100"
src="{{{.}}}"
alt="{{#str}} pictureof, core, {{name}} {{/str}}"
aria-hidden="true"
title="{{#str}} pictureof, core, {{name}} {{/str}}"
>
</a>
{{/urls.image}}
```

When I traced the files, I do not understand how the URL is passed to the template as rendering context.
How do I get this URL from blocks/news_items/blocks_news_items.php file?

Comment: You'll need to check some things about moodle development :
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API
https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Context
This should be a good start about your inquiry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ChatGPT solved this